# Google Chrome: Setting keyboard focus to bars

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In Chrome there are sometimes various bars, like the download bar, translation bar, remember password bar, etc. How do I put keyboard focus on these bars? I want to be able to use Chrome while touching the mouse as little as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hotkey info here: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650 it doesn't seem that there is a way to interact with the Downloads bar like you want, but there is the shortcut to open the Downloads tab, Ctrl+J.  Used in combination with regular keyboard navigation, you can navigate through your downloads on that page.  It appears F6 and Shift+F6 will navigate between webpage content and address/bookmark bars.  I haven't tested this with the Translate bar.